# Delete specific row in ALV?

Tags: abap, alv

I want to delete a specific row in a table. I identified the row before using `get_selected_rows`. Now I have the row identified in `gt_rows`.

Now I want to delete that row. I just can't get it done. Here's my current code:

```
    go_selec = go_alv->get_selections( ).   "gt_rows
    CALL METHOD go_selec->get_selected_rows
      RECEIVING
        value = gt_rows.
      *Here the row should get deleted.
```

The name of the database Table is "zrtable" and the name of the internal table is it_table. The name of the structure is ls_table. I'm a beginner so a bit of code would be awesome. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ABAP - ALV delete selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667607/abap-alv-delete-selected-row)

Answer (score 0):

gt_rows table holds index data of the rows which selected.

Now you have to loop at your index table to read these lines.

```
LOOP AT gt_rows ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<index>).
  READ TABLE it_table ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<table_line>) INDEX <index>. 
  IF <table_line> IS ASSIGNED.
    CLEAR <table_line>.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Also instead of READ TABLE, you can use,

```
DATA(line) = it_table[ index ].
```

Think field-symbols as pointers, you directly access to data using them, so they point the reference not value.